# set intent's display size and position it if it is possible

Tags: android, image, android-intent, size, call

I'm new to android so I appreciate all the comments you have.

I want to call a new Intent from a BroadcastReceiver.
Is it possible to set the displayed size of the new intent and position it?

Precisely, I would like to place a custom picture on top of the incoming
call screen and still be able to answer or reject the call.

I could do it with toast, but it disappears after I while and I don't want that
to happen.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> I want to call a new Intent from a BroadcastReceiver

You do not "call a new `Intent`" in Android.

> Is it possible to set the displayed size of the new intent and position it?

I am assuming that by "call a new `Intent`" you mean "start an activity", and by "set the displayed size of the new `Intent`" you mean "set the displayed size of the activity".

In that case, the code that is *starting* the activity has no control over the *rendering* of that activity. The *implementer* of the activity is the one that controls the rendering. It is possible for an activity to not fill the screen and have control over its size. I presume that it is possible for the activity to control where it is on the screen, though I haven't looked into that.

> I would like to place a custom picture on top of the incoming call screen and still be able to answer or reject the call

That is both impossible and impractical.

It is impossible because only the foreground activity gets user input. Your activity that will "place a custom picture" will receive all input; the incoming-call screen will not receive input, and so the user cannot accept or reject the call.

It is impractical because across thousands of Android device models there are dozens, if not hundreds, of incoming-call screen implementations, none of which have to look the same. As a result, you have no way of knowing whether your "custom picture" will visually overlay important things in the incoming-call screen, such as the buttons to accept or reject the call.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
I need to write the app for a specified model so that wouldn't be a problem.
I was thinking about making the top layer activity containing the picture transparent. This way I can see my picture and the incoming call screen too, but as you said the call screen won't answer to ontouchevents, im looking for a solution for that problem.